# Dual Monitor RDP - User Friendly

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

So we're testing out ubuntu 16.04 on some old PCs so that they can hopefully be reconfigured into rdp clients. I know there are alternatives (such as thinstation) but for a number of reasons we couldn't use something like that. I figured that the most user friendly choice would be ubuntu and using Remmina. Unfortunately a lot of our users have dual monitors, which Remmina doesn't support.

I've got freerdp to work with this, and that's fine, but it's not quite what I'd call user friendly like Remmina is. I'm just wondering if there's a suitable alternative in this case - I've been using freerdp through the terminal, but if there's a more user-friendly way to do this I'm all ears! I've done some research and I can't find much. I've used Ubuntu in a home environment, but not really in a business one so I've not been faced with something like this before.

Any help would be appreciated! Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find much in the search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solution that I use in my company.

On clients (old PC's) we are using Lubuntu. All them have 2 or 3 monitor connected. There are created users with logins/passwords as on original windows stations.

I've created script:

```
#! /bin/bash

xfreerdp /multimon /d:DOMAIN_NAME /u:USER_NAME /p:PASSWORD /v:IP.OF.WIN.COMP +compression /multimedia +clipboard +fonts +aero /rfx
```

which is automatically executed after user logins into Lubuntu. Some people didn't notice that they are using Linux :)

Remember, option /multimon works as expected when top edges of screens are aligned in Lubuntu display settings. Additional monitors cannot have negative vertical offset (in this case remote screen will be spanned across all monitors).

There are some ”more advanced user” :) They have additional scripts which starts remote desktop on one monitor only. On second they usually have web browser running locally.

Comment: holy smokes. thanks! gave me a fully imersed windows experience!! for those using this solution, to exit, i had to do: `alt-ctrl-f3`, kill rdp via `sudo kill -9`, and head back to ubuntu desktop via `alt-ctrl-f1`.